# Why Authorize is to set to Controller in AuthComponent?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Why authorize is to set to Controller  while Authentication is done in AppController?

Like: I got it when [Blog example](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what) is doing but did not get details explanation on it

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller']
    ]);
```

I read the [Authorize Section](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize) but could not understand it. So Could someone please help making me understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is describing how you would control your own authorization at the controller level.
Authentication identifies a valid user.  If any logged in user may access any part of your app, then you don't need to implement any further authorization.  But if you wish to restrict access to certain controllers, based on *role* for example, you could set `'authorize' => ['Controller']` in the Auth config as described, and then in each controller define your own `isAuthorized()` method, based on the role of the user.

For example, if in your InvoicesController you only want to let users whose role is 'Accounting' access the methods, you could include a test for that in an isAuthorized() method in the InvoicesController:

```
// src/Controller/InvoicesController.php
class InvoicesController extends AppController
{
    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        if ($user['role'] === 'Accounting'){
            return true;
        }
        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }

    // other methods
}
```